# Add Run with elevated privileges in JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-addin, csom, jsom, runwithelevatedprivileges

- I writing JSOM code to get interact with sharepoint 2013 lists and
  document libraries.Now I have requirement to allow anonymous users
  to insert the items for SharePoint Lists   list.
- Can any one help me in knowing how can I use
  SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated in JSOM Code

Comment: try this link: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/06/13/how-to-allow-anonymous-users-to-add-items-to-sharepoint-list-using-client-object-model.aspx

Comment: You will not be able to elevate permissions via JSOM. For that you would need to have your own web service

Comment: Imagine what would happen if elevating permissions was possible in JS. Every user could open browser console and execute any operation against the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use elevated privileges in Client Object Model. This would open up a huge security hole. You can use elevated privileges on SSOM, where are supposed that the deploy of a page or component has been approved by someone. Instead anyone could execute client code from anywhere and hack a site.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot elevate privileges in JavaScript CSOM, nor would you want to.  Remember there is nothing stopping end users from crafting their own scripts and running them via a developer tool like IE's Developer Tools or Firebug.  If you could elevate privileges via JavaScript, it could mean disaster on your Farm as regular users could just write a script to elevate their permissions and make some major changes.

If you need to do this from the browser, look at either a custom application page or a web service that could run on a server where you could properly elevate privileges.

You can refer this link for more information,

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/835b0d48-8fb5-47d4-bc1a-502c18f59568/runwithelevatedprivileges-in-share-point-client-object-model

Comment: Thanks for your support all and providing me important information.
I am site administrator and I don't have any access to Web-application in Central administration.
Can any one help me in knowing Is it possible to do with any other client side program